# Regex Extract ( left part of the string from 1 underscore before 1)

Tags: sql, regex

I want to Extract the data from a string (left data from XXX-1 underscore)
E.g 
I have a sting like

A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H_I_J
I want the data from A to D 
My F is constant so i can use String Before F.

Please help me on this

Comment: There is `E` also between `A` to `D` and `F`. Why don't you want that `E` if you say before `F`? May be you should rephrase what you want in a correct and clear manner.

Comment: I am doing this in Legacy sql

Comment: Also, being a new SO user, I'll suggest you to please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and specifically [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it helps others and in turn they can help you back, else your post may be downvoted (although I didn't downvote your post) and closed.

Comment: Not sure what you want. To match everything in a string before the first "F", you write `^[^F]*`. But what, for instance, do you mean by "1 underscore"?

Comment: quikr_ccr_fc=Jobs_Full Time Jobs_Office Assistant/Helper_APPLY_SUCCESS_dc=Jobs_Freelancers_BPO/ telecaller_4_click ... this is the sting... i need the complete data till _dc=.....in legacy sql

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/3hXoQe/1/

"/([_A-Z]*?)F/"
() = capturing group
[] = allowed characters, so [_A-Z] accepts any uppercase letter and "_"
*?F = until it finds letter F

Do you mean that?